# What is the name of this type of art?

Tags: graphic-styles, art

I really like the art an graphics that twitter does. It looks really cool.

I wanna know what is the name of this type of background :

[image]

I mean is it gradient? Or... IDK. Please help. I really like this type of art

Comment: ermm.. scratchy? Distressed? Not everything has some specific name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very sure but it should be the **Vintage Scratchy** background.
You can refer to this [link](https://pixabay.com/) if you wanna find some similar backgrounds.